# Speed up Gstreamer pipeline while keeping video and audio in sync

Tags: python, gstreamer, video-processing, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I have a Gstreamer pipeline with 2 appsinks that provide raw video and audio buffers to a Python program that stores these buffers to disk. The end goal is to split video in seperate frames and audio samples that belong to that frame and store them to disk. For example if I have 2 seconds of video at 25 FPS I would like to get 100 files with images and 100 files with raw audio chunks. Simplified schematics for the current pipeline look like this:
[image]

The problem here is that I want to run the pipeline as fast as possible and for that I need to have the appsink property `sync` set to  `False` . But then the audio and video buffers are out of sink and I need to do some complex processing in the app to store aligned video and audio buffers. If I have `sync` set to `True` then the pipeline's maximal speed is the native framerate of the video.

It seems that there should be a simpler solution to run the pipeline as fast as possible and keep video and audio buffers in sync. Something like this perhaps?
[image]

I am looking for someone more experienced in Gstreamer that could point me in the right direction. More specifically I wish to know if there is a way to run first pipeline at maximal possible speed without loosing synchronisation or how to implement a custom muxer that would just combine video and audio buffers and pass them to the appsink with `sync` property set to `False`

Comment: Sync is lways handled via timestamps. How do you actually sync audio ind video in the first place then? Processing speed should not be relevant here.

Comment: If I have sync set to true on the appsinks the pipeline with speed equal  to framerate of the video. If i have it set to false the pipeline runs as fast as possible. Currently I have it set to false and I do the  synchronisation in python code (in the appsink). It runs approximately 3 times faster this way.

Comment: Yes but the question is: what is sync in your current implementation? You just require audio and video that belongs together to arrive in the same point in time? That's the worst you can do. Each buffer should carry a timestamp. You identify which sample belongs to what looking at these. Then processing speed is no longer relevant.

Comment: No I use the buffer timestamps to match audio and video frames up. But this is done in python code. I would imagine that Gstreamer would have that natively, I just don't know how to use it correctly. The only way I found to run the pipeline as fast as possible is with sync off in the appsinks and then match up the buffers based on timestamps in python code..... OMG! I think I just found a solution audio appsink sync needs to be ON and video appsink sync needs to be OFF then it seems that all is synced and runs at the max speed of video streeam.... need to do some testing to be shure now

Comment: Nah my bad, then audio stream is running at only the frame rate of the video. Thought it would sync it to the fastest sink